# How to get accurate numeric value returned to shell from oracle function

Tags: oracle, shell, numeric

I have a function in oracle. The function will return numeric value (something like 20140513212746 which are 14 digit long). The function will be called by shell script. But the shell script is not returning exact value that is returned by the function.

for example, if the value in oracle is 9999110300002, the shell is returning it as 9999100000000

Below is the shell script code block

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlresult=`sqlplus -S scott/tiger<<EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SELECT fn_getExecNo@db_link_name ('<HOST_NAME_TO_SEARCH>') FROM DUAL;
EOF`
echo $sqlresult
execno=`echo $sqlresult | awk '{printf( "%d", $1 )}'`
echo $execno
```

the result is

```
calling function ....
9.9991E+12 and
9999100000000
```

Either the return data type of oracle function is NUMERIC or VARCHAR, the value do not changes in shell.

How can I get the exact value returned by oracle function in shell? This value need to be compared with value in shell variable itself.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlresult=`sqlplus -S scott/tiger<<EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
alter session set nls_numeric_characters='. ';
SELECT to_char(fn_getExecNo@db_link_name ('<HOST_NAME_TO_SEARCH>'), 'tm') FROM DUAL;
EOF`
echo $sqlresult
execno=`echo $sqlresult | awk '{printf( "%d", $1 )}'`
echo $execno
```

Comment: Thanks nop77svk. This is working fine. I do not need to use awk.